# How to clone a tab with same data in laravel php

Tags: javascript, html

so im trying to do a cloning function. So i have put two tabs and a button to add a tab, so when i click that button a new tab with "LEG 2" suppose to be created with the same data as in previous tabs. How can i do that?

```html
<ul id="tabs" class="nav nav-tabs nav-tabs-linetriangle" data-init-reponsive-tabs="dropdownfx">
    <li  class="active">
        <a data-toggle="tab" href="#1"><span>LEG 1</span></a>
    </li>

    <li>
        <button class="btn alt-btn-black btn-xs alt-btn newTravelLegButton" type="button" >
            <i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true" color="black"></i>
        </button>
    </li>
</ul>
```

```html
<div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="1">
        <div class="row">
           sdfsdfdsfsf
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: in this case you need javascript or jQuery

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/34761719/5413785 and you can easily use the clone function of jquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add following jQuery code in your view to achieve your requirement:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var i = 1;
    $('.newTravelLegButton').click(function(){
        $('#tabs li').removeClass('active');
        $('.tab-pane').removeClass('active');
        i++;
        tabHTML = '<li  class="active">';
        tabHTML += '<a data-toggle="tab" href="#1"><span>LEG '+i+'</span></a>';
        tabHTML += '</li>';

       contentHTML = '<div class="tab-pane active" id="'+i+'">';
        contentHTML += '<div class="row">';
        contentHTML += $('#'+(i-1)).html();
        contentHTML += '</div>';
        contentHTML += '</div>';

       lastLI = $('.newTravelLegButton').closest('li');
        $( tabHTML ).insertBefore( lastLI );
        $('.tab-content').append(contentHTML);

   });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Hi first of all thank you so much for this solution. It worked. Secondly, now it is cloning the whole web page as it is supposed to do, but how i do clone it to create another page as in the same page with 2 array.